# Prove that A is a subset of B.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

A={p odd prime | p= ${a}^2+ 15b$ for some a,b ∈ Z}

B={p odd prime | p= $5k+1$ for some k ∈ Z or p= $5l-1$ for some l ∈ Z}

I'm really confused on how to calculate the choices for (a,b). Do you use the Euclidean Algorithm?

Comment: Consider their elements modulo $5$.

Comment: Okay. So would a= $5l, 5l+1, 5l +2, 5l+3, 5l+4 $ or a= $15l $, etc.?

Comment: Mostly the first. But you will have to use a separate argument to deal with the case $p=5$.

Answer (score 1):

If you are asking to prove that  $A \subset B$, then we may  proceed as follows:

Let $p \in A$, the  $p=15b+a^2$ for some  $a,b \in  \mathbb{Z}$.

If $a^2 \equiv 0 $ (mod $5$), then  $5$ divides $a^2$, and so  $5$ divides  $a^2+15 b$, i.e. $5$ divides  $p$, but $p$ is considered prime, hence this does not hold. So we may consider that  $a^2$ will never be congruent to  zero  (mod $5$).

Hence for any  $a^2 \equiv \pm 1 $ (mod $5$) (easy to check), and so   $a^2=5s+1$ or  $a^2=5t-1$ with $t,s \in \mathbb{Z}$. Hence $p=5(3b)+ 5s+1$ or $p=5(3b)+ 5t-1$, i.e.  $p=5(3b+s)+1$ or $p=5(3b+ t)-1$ with  $t,s \in \mathbb{Z}$. Therefore  $p \in B$, and so  $A \subset B$.

Comment: This doesn't quite address the case where $a \equiv 0 \pmod 5$.

Comment: @DavidSchneider-Joseph note that if  $a \equiv 0$ (mod $5$), hen so is  $a^2$, and so  $p=15b+a^2$ is divisible by  $5$, but $p$ is prime, hence contraction. Thus we may exclude this case from the beginning.  Note also that  $p \in A$ cannot be  $5$.